# error while inserting data into database express/mongodb app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Aloha, i was trying to insert data from a form into my database unfortunately there's an error keep showing up and i don't understand why, the error is `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` and i keep getting `something is wrong` in code which i console.log it indicate something is wrong in my database

UPDATED

this is the error currently i get http://imgur.com/ROl06t7

```
{ [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: symsal.users.$username_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: symsal.users.$username_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 84,
  ok: 1 }
```

### my code

```
 this.handleSignup = function(req, res, next) {
        "use strict";
    validateSignup(req.body, function(error, data) {
        if(error) {
            res.send(400, error.message);
        } else {
            users.addUser(data, function(err, user) {
                "use strict";
                sessions.startSession(data, function(err, session_id) {
                    "use strict";
                    if (err) return next(err);
                    res.cookie('session', session_id);
                });
            });
            res.send(200);
        }
    })

    }
```

### addUser

```
 this.addUser = function(data,callback) {
        "use strict";

        var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
        var password_hash = bcrypt.hashSync(data.password, salt);
        var user = {
            '_id': data.email,
            'email':data.email,
            'password': password_hash,
            'firstName': data.firstName,
            'lastName': data.lastName,
            'penName': data.penName,
            'publicUsername':data.publicUsername
        };
        console.log(user);
        users.insert(user, function (err, result) {
            "use strict";

            if (!err) {
                console.log("Inserted new user");
                return callback(null, result[0]);
            }else{
                console.log("Something is wrong");
            }

            return callback(err, null);
        });
    }
```

if delete `return callback(err, null);` the `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` will not show up but it still display `"Something is wrong"` in my terminal. is there any mistake in my code ? i believe `return callback(err, null);` is to tell the application there's an error and return null to the application.

hope you guys can help me thank you

Comment: Quick answer, not fully tested.  Did you try commenting out `res.send(200)` or moving it inside `users.addUser()` or `sessions.startSession(...)`?  I find that error occurs when there are two spots in the code that try sending responses.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, i have tested your solution, the Error: Can't set headers after they are sent is not showing up anymore but i still get "Something is wrong" in my terminal which mean i still can't insert my data into my database

Comment: `if (err) console.log(err);` should give you (and us) a bit more information.

Comment: { [MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: symsal.users.$username_1  dup key: { : null }]
  name: 'MongoError',
  err: 'E11000 duplicate key error index: symsal.users.$username_1  dup key: { : null }',
  code: 11000,
  n: 0,
  connectionId: 82,
  ok: 1 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that you have declared that the `username` property should be unique, yet you're trying to insert a new document with a `username` that already exists in the database.

Since you're not actually setting the `username` property on your document, MongoDB will insert a `null` value for each new document (and inserting a second `null` value for a unique property will also violate the uniqueness constraint).

If you're not using the `username` property anymore, you should remove the unique index on it. From the MongoDB shell, that would look something like this:

```
db.users.dropIndex({ username : 1 })
```

If you do want to keep using it, but don't want to have MongoDB insert a `null` if you don't declare the `username` property on a document, use the [`sparse`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#create-a-unique-index) option.